# Mapping CLR and SQL SERVER data types in UDF

Tags: c#, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create an UDF in C#. The C# function returns a string and I need to return it as CHAR(40) from the UDF.

The c# function basically is

```
public static string functionname() {
   return "mystring";
}
```

The UDF is created with

```
create function functionname() returns char(40) 
as external name NameSpace.Class.functionname;
```

I tried different return types and annotations for the C# function, but didn't get the right combination.

Return types of `string` or `SqlString` create an error with the SQL script like `CREATE FUNCTION for functionname failed because T-SQL and CLR types for return value do not match.`

A return type of `SqlChars` doesn't compile with error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars'`

It does work if I return NCHAR(40) from the UDF, but I need CHAR(40).

How can I achieve it?

Comment: There appears to be no CLR mapping type for SQL `char`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: ".NET Framework SVFs are implemented as methods on a class in a .NET Framework assembly. The input parameters and the type returned from a SVF can be any of the scalar data types supported by SQL Server, except varchar, char, rowversion, text, ntext, image, timestamp, table, or cursor. " taken from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Alex Thanks for pointing this out. I found the first reference before but couldn't really believe it. But the second reference leaves no doubt :-( Looks like I need to cast the result on sql server side.